# How to turn off `emacs-lisp-checkdoc` of flycheck when edit source block in org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, flycheck

I have a `emacs-lisp` block in org-mode and when I try to edit it by press `C-c '`, flycheck always report errors as below:

```
0     warning         The first line should be of the form: ";;; package --- Summary"... (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)
0     warning         You should have a section marked ";;; Commentary:"... (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)
1     warning         You should have a section marked ";;; Code:"... (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)
```

How could I turn it off when edit it source block?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## tl;dr

Disable the checker emacs-lisp-checkdoc with the `org-src-mode-hook`.

```el
(defun disable-fylcheck-in-org-src-block ()
  (setq-local flycheck-disabled-checkers '(emacs-lisp-checkdoc)))

(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook 'disable-fylcheck-in-org-src-block)
```

## Detailed walkthrough how to find this information

First search for possible variables which change the behaviour of Flycheck. There are several ways to do this:

- Use `M-x describe-variable`.
- If there are a lot of them then `M-x customize-group` `<package>` `RET` is always a good place to look up common candidates.
- A third way would be to use `M-x apropos-documentation` which searches the dosctrings of all symbols in Emacs.
- Yet another way to find information would be to look up if there is an info page for the package. In case of Flycheck there is. `M-x info`. Use `M-x Info-menu` to jump to desired Info page and search around there.`M-x Info-index` and `M-x Info-search` are useful for this.

*I would highly recommend to use a completion framework like helm, ido, icicles or any other because with enhanced minibuffer completion the methods above a far more convenient.*

In this case after some digging and trying out the methods above one may find:

```el
> Flycheck Disabled Checkers:
  Syntax checkers excluded from automatic selection.
```

Ok now we know the variable we want to change. We only want to change it when editing source blocks in org-mode. If you check `M-x describe-mode` and look for an enabled minor-mode that starts with org you will find:

```el
Org-Src minor mode (no indicator):
Minor mode for language major mode buffers generated by org.
```

Know that we know the mode we search for a hook for this mode. As almost always it is just a -hook appended to the mode name: `org-src-mode-hook`.

Most of the time there are multiple methods in Emacs to do stuff. I hope this helps beginners, I know how I was lost in the beginning. Don't be intimidated, when you use the techniques above several times you don't think about it anymore.