# How do I disable a flymake backend?

Tags: flymake

I'm looking to follow [this other answer regarding linting inside org-mode source code block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16770/690) but I'm not able to figure out how to tell flymake to disable certain backends.

I'm using Emacs 27.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `flymake-diagnostic-functions`:

> The functions in this hook diagnose problems in a buffer’s contents and provide information to the Flymake user interface about where and how to annotate problems diagnosed in a buffer.

Just remove function that you don't need like this:

```el
(remove-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions 'flymake-function-that-you-dont-need)
```