# How do I disable grammar checking in orgmode code blocks

Tags: org-mode, flycheck

I installed this package https://github.com/emacs-languagetool/flycheck-languagetool to use languagetool with emacs. However, I am getting languagetool errors at my org documents' code blocks too. How would I disable flycheck to run spell checking at my code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16766/how-to-turn-off-emacs-lisp-checkdoc-of-flycheck-when-edit-source-block-in-org) almost gives you the answer, which is:

```
(defun disable-fylcheck-in-org-src-block ()
  (setq-local flycheck-disabled-checkers '(languagetool)))
  
(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook 'disable-fylcheck-in-org-src-block)
```

Comment: Almost… Description of `org-src-mode-hook` says: 
This hook will run:
- when editing a source code snippet with ‘C-c '’
- when formatting a source code snippet for export with htmlize.

However, I want to disable it in the org buffer.

In my case flycheck  already runs the correct linter/checker in the src-mode.